How do I get variable length slices of values using Pandas?
I have data that includes a full name and first name, and I need to make a new column with the last name. I can assume full - first = last.
I've been trying to use slice with an index the length of the first name + 1. But that index is a series, not an integer. So it's returning NaN.
The commented lines show the things I tried. It took me a while to realize what the series/integer issue was. It seems this shouldn't be so difficult.
Thanks
import pandas as pd

columns = ['Full', 'First']
data = [('Joe Smith', 'Joe'), ('Bobby Sue Ford', 'Bobby Sue'), ('Current Resident', 'Current Resident'), ('', '')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

#first_chars = df['First'].str.len() + 1

#last = df['Full'].str[4:]
#last = df['Full'].str[first_chars:]
#last = df['Full'].str.slice(first_chars)
#last = df.Full.str[first_chars:]
#pd.DataFrame.insert(df, loc=2, column='Last', value=last)

#df['Last'] = df.Full.str[first_chars:]
#df['Last'] = str(df.Full.str[first_chars:])

#first_chars = int(first_chars)
#df['Last'] = df['Full'].apply(str).apply(lambda x: x[first_chars:])
df['Last'] = df['Full'].str.slice(df['First'].str.len() + 1)

print(df)


Edit:
Use removeprefix instead of replace to deal with cases where first and last names are the same:
df['Last'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Full'].removeprefix(row['First']).strip(), axis=1)

               Full             First   Last
0         Joe Smith               Joe  Smith
1    Bobby Sue Ford         Bobby Sue   Ford
2  Current Resident  Current Resident       
3                                           
4           Joe Joe               Joe    Joe


Original answer:
Use apply on axis=1 to replace each name:
df['Last'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Full'].replace(row['First'], '').strip(), axis=1)

               Full             First   Last
0         Joe Smith               Joe  Smith
1    Bobby Sue Ford         Bobby Sue   Ford
2  Current Resident  Current Resident       
3        


Both answers that were posted worked. I'm going with this one because, to me, it's immediately clear what you're doing. Thank you!

IIUC, you can do it this way using string slicing, list comprehension, and zip:
df['Last'] = [u[len(i)+1:] for u, i in zip(df['Full'], df['First'])]

Output:
               Full             First   Last
0         Joe Smith               Joe  Smith
1    Bobby Sue Ford         Bobby Sue   Ford
2  Current Resident  Current Resident       
3                                           

Details:

Use zip to to a list of tuples of (Full, First) pairs.
Create a list comprehension looping through this list.
For each element in the list, take the first element of the tuple, u and string slice it based on the length plus 1 of the second element  in the tuple, i.


@JWeb This should be more efficient than apply with axis=1
